# Centralizar tabela na pagina latex

Tags: latex

Estou tendo problema com a centralização de uma tabela em `latex`. Ela está comendo texto esta da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em meu código programei assim:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                     APÊNDICE                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APÊNDICE}
\begin{flushleft}
    {\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont {\bf APÊNDICE}} \\
    {\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont {\bf Lista de funções do projeto}}
\end{flushleft}

\thispagestyle{myheadings}

\fontsize{12}{10}\linespread{2.2}\selectfont
{

\noindent
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{FUNÇÕES DO PROJETO}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|l|l|c|c|@{}}
\hline
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{TIPO} & \textbf{REQUISITO}          & \textbf{DESCRIÇÃO}                     & \textbf{TEMPO ESTIMADO} & \textbf{TEMPO REALIZADO} \\ \hline
1           &  1            & Cadastrar parâmetros        &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de parâmetros      &   12        &     12                          \\ \hline
2           &  1            & Cadastrar Produtos          &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de produtos        &   120       &     120                         \\ \hline
3           &  1            & Cadastrar Categoria         &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de categorias      &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
4           &  1            & Cadastrar Sub Categoria     &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de sub categorias  &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
5           &  1            & Cadastrar Promoção          &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de promoções       &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
6           &  1            & Cadastrar Tipo de produto   &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de tipos de produto&   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
7           &  1            & Cadastrar Embalagens        &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de embalagens      &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
8           &  1            & Cadastrar Imagem            &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de imagens         &   12        &     12                          \\ \hline
9           &  1            & Cadastrar Lote              &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de lotes           &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
10          &  2            & Analisar encomenda          &  O administrador altera o status da encomenda      &   5         &     5                           \\ \hline
11          &  2            & Encomenda produtos          &  O cliente encomenda produtos listados             &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
12          &  2            & Consultar produtos          &  O cliente consulta produtos listados              &   10        &     10                          \\ \hline
13          &  2            &Consultar histórico de compra&  O cliente visualiza o histórico das compras       &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
14          &  2            & Consultar cadastro          &  O cliente pode alterar seus dados cadastrais      &   5         &     5                           \\ \hline
15          &  2            &           &           &                &                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

}
```

Como posso resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tente adicionar o seguinte código `\centering`

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que deva ter resolvido seu problema, mas caso alguém ainda esteja com a dúvida.

Você pode utilizar o seguinte comando antes do seu tabular, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APÊNDICE}
\begin{flushleft}
    {\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont {\bf APÊNDICE}} \\
    {\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont {\bf Lista de funções do projeto}}
\end{flushleft}

\thispagestyle{myheadings}

\fontsize{12}{10}\linespread{2.2}\selectfont
{

\noindent
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{FUNÇÕES DO PROJETO}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ % <----- Acrescente esta linha
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|l|l|c|c|@{}}
\hline
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{TIPO} & \textbf{REQUISITO}          & \textbf{DESCRIÇÃO}                     & \textbf{TEMPO ESTIMADO} & \textbf{TEMPO REALIZADO} \\ \hline
1           &  1            & Cadastrar parâmetros        &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de parâmetros      &   12        &     12                          \\ \hline
2           &  1            & Cadastrar Produtos          &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de produtos        &   120       &     120                         \\ \hline
3           &  1            & Cadastrar Categoria         &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de categorias      &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
4           &  1            & Cadastrar Sub Categoria     &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de sub categorias  &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
5           &  1            & Cadastrar Promoção          &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de promoções       &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
6           &  1            & Cadastrar Tipo de produto   &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de tipos de produto&   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
7           &  1            & Cadastrar Embalagens        &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de embalagens      &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
8           &  1            & Cadastrar Imagem            &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de imagens         &   12        &     12                          \\ \hline
9           &  1            & Cadastrar Lote              &  Inclusão, alteração e exclusão de lotes           &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
10          &  2            & Analisar encomenda          &  O administrador altera o status da encomenda      &   5         &     5                           \\ \hline
11          &  2            & Encomenda produtos          &  O cliente encomenda produtos listados             &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
12          &  2            & Consultar produtos          &  O cliente consulta produtos listados              &   10        &     10                          \\ \hline
13          &  2            &Consultar histórico de compra&  O cliente visualiza o histórico das compras       &   8         &     8                           \\ \hline
14          &  2            & Consultar cadastro          &  O cliente pode alterar seus dados cadastrais      &   5         &     5                           \\ \hline
15          &  2            &           &           &                &                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}% <----- importante acrescentar este símbolo
} <----- acrescente esta linha.
\end{table}
}
```

Bom trabalho.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta usar o seguinte parâmetro no \begin{table}:

```
\begin{table}[c]
```

o parametro c é de center, veja se dá certo.

Comment: Não solucionou meu problema.